# Changing colour of line plot on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to manually set the colours for a slightly complex graph on ggplot. I am aiming to be able to manually select the colours for the plot, however I do not seem to be able to set the colours through scale_fill_manual[I have attached the current graph, I am looking to be able to set the couours of the lines and the dots dependedent on the group][1]

My code for the graph is:

```
table(danz$Pathology)

#SELECT Variables in a pipe
dangraph<- danz %>% filter(!is.na(Pathology)) %>% select(Pathology,
                                                         zScoregfap, zScoreS100B,  zScoreUCHL1, zScoreTau, zScoreNSE,  zScoreNFL) %>% pivot_longer(-Pathology)  

cbp1 <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73",
          #"#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")

ggplot(dangraph[which(dangraph$Pathology=="No acute abnormality" | dangraph$Pathology=="Skull Fracture" | dangraph$Pathology=="EDH"|  dangraph$Pathology=="acute SDH" | dangraph$Pathology=="SAH" | dangraph$Pathology=="Intraparenchymal haemorrhage" | dangraph$Pathology=="DAI" | dangraph$Pathology=="Mixed Lesion"),], aes(x=name,y=value, colour=Pathology, group=Pathology)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbp1) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean,geom="point", size=5) +
  stat_summary(fun=mean,aes(group=Pathology, fill=Pathology),geom="line",size=2.5, linetype = "solid") +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_se,geom="errorbar",width=0.1, size=1,  colour = "black", linetype = "solid")+
  xlab("Biomarker") + ylab("Mean Z-Score")+
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "A - Biomarker Z score signatures for different CT findings
       
       ") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("GFAP", "NFL", "NSE", "S100B", "Tau", "UCH-L1")) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=25), axis.title=element_text(size=30)) +
   theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.text=element_text(size=30)) +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=30))


ggsave("E:/CT_Biomarkers_Paper/Output_Plots/Zscore.jpg",  dpi = 1000, height = 10, width= 18.75)
```

The scale_fill_manual section of the above code does not seem to make a difference.

Many thanks for your help.

Dan
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPAz9.jpg

Comment: Does replacing `scale_fill_manual()` with `scale_colour_manual()` help at all?

Answer (score 0):

As @teunbrand said - replacing with scale-colour-manual was the trick. Easy solutions but hard for us novices!